# FullCalendar on Salesforce - How to query and display events according to selected view dates?

Tags: javascript, salesforce, fullcalendar, visualforce, apex

I'm trying to make use FullCalendar on Salesforce.
i cant allow the query to get all the events because it's too much data so what i want to do is fetch events according to the current dates on the view (using start and end dates).
i got the dates sent correctly to the apex code so i can query between those dates.

problem is that i cant find a way to display the result
my event list looks good on debug log
but calendar looks empty.

Thanks :)

here's the visualforce code:

```
<apex:page controller="Calendar_Controller" >

<link href="{!$Resource.fullCalendarCSS}" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="{!$Resource.fullCalendarPrintCSS}" rel="stylesheet" media="print" />
<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.moment_min_js}"  />﻿

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="{!$Resource.fullCalendarMinJS}"></script>

<script>

    //We need to wrap everything in a doc.ready function so that the code fires after the DOM is loaded

    $(document).ready(function() {   

        //Call the fullCallendar method. You can replace the '#calendar' with the ID of the dom element where you want the calendar to go. 

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },

                editable: true,

            events: function(start,end,callback){
                var d = new Date(start);
                var StartStr = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd ', d);
                d = new Date(end);
                var EndStr = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', d);
                DeleteQuoteLineItem(''+StartStr,''+EndStr,''+callback, function(result, event)
                                    {
                                     if(true)
                                     {         
                                         var theControllerValue = '{!events}';
                                         callback(theControllerValue);
                                     }
                                    }, {escape:true});            
                //DeleteQuoteLineItem(''+StartStr,''+EndStr,''+callback);
                var theControllerValue = '{!events}';
                callback(theControllerValue);

            },


            eventDrop:                 
            function(event,dayDelta,minuteDelta,allDay,revertFunc) {                                
                    if (!confirm(event.title+ " ישתנה " + dayDelta + " ימים, האם לאשר את השינוי?")) {
                    //REVERT IF NO
                        revertFunc();
                    }else{                                            
                    //ELSE 


                        //changeeventdate(event.eventID,dayDelta,minuteDelta);
                    }

                }

        });



    });



</script>



<!--some styling. Modify this to fit your needs-->

<style>

    #cal-options {float:left;}
    #cal-legend { float:right;}
    #cal-legend ul {margin:0;padding:0;list-style:none;}
    #cal-legend ul li {margin:0;padding:5px;float:left;}
    #cal-legend ul li span {display:block; height:16px; width:16px; margin-right:4px; float:left; border-radius:4px;}
    #calendar {margin-top:20px;}
    #calendar a:hover {color:#fff !important;}
    .fc-event-inner {padding:3px;}
    .event-birthday {background:#56458c;border-color:#56458c;}
    .group-babies {background:#cc9933;border-color:#cc9933;}
    .group-hydro {background:#00b300;border-color:#00b300;}
    .group-learning {background:#993399;border-color:#993399;}
    .event-personal {background:#1797c0;border-color:#1797c0;}
</style>
<apex:sectionHeader title="My Calendar Example"/>

<apex:outputPanel id="calPanel">
    <apex:form >


        <apex:actionFunction action="{!DeleteQuoteLineItem}" name="DeleteQuoteLineItem" reRender="content">
            <apex:param name="myParam1" value=""/>
            <apex:param name="myParam2" value=""/>
            <apex:param name="myParam3" value=""/>
        </apex:actionFunction>


        <div id="cal-options">
            <apex:commandButton value="{!IF(includeMyEvents,'Hide My Events','Show My Events')}" action="{!toggleMyEvents}"/>
        </div>
        <div id="cal-legend">
            <ul>
                <li><span class="event-birthday"></span>ימי הולדת</li>
                <li><span class="group-hydro"></span>הידרותרפיה</li>
                <li><span class="group-learning"></span>שיעור שחיה</li>
                <li><span class="group-babies"></span>שחיית תינוקות</li>
                <!--<li style="{!IF(includeMyEvents,'','display:none')}"><span class="event-personal"></span>My Events</li>-->
            </ul>
            <div style="clear:both;"><!--fix floats--></div>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both;"><!--fix floats--></div>
        <div id="calendar"></div>
    </apex:form>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: `var theControllerValue = '{!events}';` just sends a string to fullCalendar, not a list of events. I don't know what this syntax is supposed to be. I can't see any kind of ajax call to your server in here, either. Have you read https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/ and/or https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/? The scenario in the second link is much easier to set up if you can make your server-side method compliant.

Comment: Hi, ajax call is happening from actionFunction with id "DeleteQouteLineItem" (temp name while trying to figure out whats wrong).
server side is working fine...

just having truble getting the events back from th "events" list

Comment: ok. But what variable represents the events coming back from the ajax call? Because what you are sending to fullCalendar (via the "callback" method) is just a literal string `'{!events}'` I'm guessing maybe you should be feeding all or part of the `result` or `event` variables back to fullCalendar? I don't know which one of them contains the list of events, but presumably one of them does

Comment: Also `''+callback` in your call to the DeleteQuoteLineItem method makes no sense, because "callback" is a function, not a string. I don't know why you're passing it to your method. "DeleteQuoteLineItem" is also an odd name for a method which gets events from the server. Why not call it "getEvents" or something else meaningful?

Comment: Lastly, you should entirely remove the copy of `var theControllerValue = '{!events}';
                callback(theControllerValue);` which is outside your "DeleteQuoteLineItem" method. It does nothing useful, but might cause confusion.